# LORA-E5 with BME68x - code stop in function HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady

Tags: stm32, i2c

I am currently working on integrating the Wio-e5 LoRa (https://www.seeedstudio.com/LoRa-E5-Dev-Kit-p-4868.html) with the Grove BME688 Gas Sensor (https://www.seeedstudio.com/Grove-Gas-Sensor-BME688-p-5478.html) using the I2C protocol.

I have been following the example provided on the GitHub repository (https://github.com/Squieler/BME68x-STM32-HAL/tree/main) to guide me through the integration process. Specifically, I have set the I2C peripheral to communicate with the BME688 sensor at the address 0x76.

My issue arises when I attempt to check the readiness of the I2C communication using the HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady function. The code seems to get stuck in this function, and I'm unable to proceed with the communication between the devices.

This is my first time using these components.

Comment: OK. Have you debugged where and why it gets stuck inside that function, and do you know if the chip supports being probed with that function?

Comment: 1) do you call __HAL_RCC_I2C1_CLK_ENABLE() (replace I2C1 by propper I2C peripheral number)? 2) Do you have pullups on SDA and SCL lines? 3) Measure voltage on SDA and SCL lines. You should measure MCU Vcc voltage (usualy 3.3V).